# why moon has a spectra, as it doesn' t have any energy source in its interior?

Tags: astrophysics

Moon doesn't have any source of energy, what does causes the spectra of moon to form? Is the spectrum seen is due to the sun.

Comment: Because of the same reason why all other visible things around us are visible.

Comment: A good search term is "reflectance spectroscopy."

Answer (score 2):

Because the moon has a temperature, it emits "black body radiation', which is electromagnetic radiation with a spectrum characteristic of the temperature.  The composition and microstructure of the surface can modify that spectrum.

Also, as you guessed, sunlight reflects off the moon's surface.  Sunlight has its own spectrum, which is modified when reflected, due to the composition and microstructure of the moon's surface.

Comment: I haven't done the arithmetic, but I would guess that reflected sunlight totally overwhelms the Moon's own blackbody radiation everywhere on the daylit side, at all wavelengths.

Comment: any body that has a temperature will show a black body spectra. but the temperature of moon is due to sun. https://www.space.com/14725-moon-temperature-lunar-days-night.html.   can we say that the spectra we see is actually that of a moon?

Comment: @Kritika, the average temperature of the Moon is due to a combination of heating by the Sun, tidal heating (if any), internal heat sources (e.g., decay of radioactive elements), and so on.  On the dark side of the Moon, there will be reflected Earthlight and reflected starlight in addition to black body radiation.  Measurement of black body radiation from a perspective on the far side of the Moon when the Moon is full or eclipsed would yield the most reliable results because then it would be possible to view places on the Moon that receive neither sunlight nor Earthlight.